# CocoaHTTPServer and Port 80, works on iPod/iPad, Permission Denied Error on the Phone

Tags: ios, asyncsocket, cocoahttpserver

so, I use the [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) to supply a website on an iOS Device.

When using an iPod Touch or an iPad with iOS 5.1 I can listen on Port 80, less hassle for the user.

Tried doing the same on my iPhone 3G, still running iOS 4.2, getting the error

```
Error starting HTTP Server: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied" UserInfo=0x3572e0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=Error in bind() function, NSLocalizedDescription=Permission denied}
```

Now I know that listening on a Port < 1024 might be restricted, but why did I have no problems on both my iPods and iPad?

Comment: 3g and wifi environment are different. Have you tried testing it over 3g net environment?

Comment: 3G makes no sense for my application, I only want to offer my service in the local wireless.

Comment: @Bersaelor Any resolution on this issue?

Comment: No, I just don't use ports < 1024 anymore since It is unclear when they are allowed and when not.